# Node.JS google oauth2 proxy failure

Tags: node.js, oauth, proxy, oauth-2.0

I am currently having problem using proxy with google oauth2 api.
It works well when not using proxy, but I have to use proxy when actually publishing the service, where the server is located in a secure network.

I use google-oauth-library which is provided by google, and https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs it says

> You can use the following environment variables to proxy HTTP and
>   HTTPS requests:
>
> HTTP_PROXY / http_proxy HTTPS_PROXY / https_proxy

So I set "HTTPS_PROXY=http://some_domain_name:3333", but it doesn't work.

I've tested following things.

1. I am using the same proxy server to proxy facebook oauth, and it works perfectly fine.
   Used the method described here(https://github.com/feathersjs/authentication-oauth2/issues/62).  So it's not a problem of proxy server itself.
2. When not using proxy, it justs gives out timeout error.
   When using proxy, it returns immediately "Failed to retrieve verification certificates: Error: socket hang up",
   and "socket hang up" is just a typical socket timeout message in nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because you have set `HTTPS_PROXY` to an `HTTP` request instead of an `HTTPS` request.

`HTTPS_PROXY=http://some_domain_name:3333`

https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs

> When HTTP_PROXY / http_proxy are set, they will be used to proxy
>   non-SSL requests that do not have an explicit proxy configuration
>   option present. Similarly, HTTPS_PROXY / https_proxy will be respected
>   for SSL requests that do not have an explicit proxy configuration
>   option.

Have you tried using

`HTTP_PROXY=http://some_domain_name:3333`